# How to do a double conditional dropdown in javascript (Onchange not working)

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I want to create a double conditional drop down with HTML and JavaScript. The first dropdown is car make, the next is car model, and the last is car variant. I have managed to create a conditional for the first two, however, the onchange for the third dropdown doesnt seem to be working

```js
function f2(){
        console.log("F2 is run")

        var make = document.getElementById("car-make").value;
        if(make == "Honda"){
            var models= ["Select Car Model","City","Amaze","Brio","Jazz","Mobilio", "BR-V", "WR-V", "Civic", "CR-V", "Accord"]
        } else if(make=="Hyundai"){
            var models= ["Select Car Model","XCENT","Verna","Tucson","Terracan","Sonata", "Santro", "Santa Fe", "i20", 
            "i10 (sedan)", "Grand i10","i10","Grandeur","Getz","Eon","Elantra"]
        } else if(make=="Renault"){
            var models= ["Select Car Model","KWID","Duster","Lodgy","Captur","Koleos", "Fluence"]
        } else{
            var models=["Select Car Model"]
        }
    
        var string = "";
        for(i=0; i<models.length; i++){
            string =string+"<option value="+models[i]+">"+models[i]+"</option>"
        }
        string="<select>"+string+"</string>"
        document.getElementById("car-model").innerHTML=string;
        var model = document.getElementById("car-model")
    }
    
    function f3(){
        console.log("F3 is run")

        var model = document.getElementById("car-model").value;
        if(model == "City"){
            var variants= ["Select Car Variant","1.5 V MT","1.5 VX MT","1.5S V MT","1.5E MT","1.5 VC VT", "1.5V XC VT", "1.5Z X CVT", "1.5 S MT", "1.5 V AT", "1.5 VX MT iDTEC"]
        } else{
            var variants=["Select Car Variant"]
        }
    
        var string = "";
        for(i=0; i<variants.length; i++){
            string =string+"<option value="+variants[i]+">"+variants[i]+"</option>"
        }
        string="<select>"+string+"</string>"
        document.getElementById("car-variant").innerHTML=string;
    }
```

```html
<select id="car-make" onchange="f2()">
        <option>Select Car Make</option>
        <option>Honda</option>
        <option>Hyundai</option>
        <option>Renault</option>
        </select>

        <select id="car-model"  onchange="f3()">
            <option>Select Car Model</option>
        </select>

        <select id="car-variant">
            <option>Select Car Variant</option>
        </select>
```

From what I've tried, function f3() doesn't seem to be running, since the dropdown for car variant remains blank, and the console only shows: "F2 is run". I think there is an issue with the (second) onchange() for car model, and have tried using onkeypress() and onclick() to fix it, but nothing has worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `f3()` is also working. See here [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-smoke-ue7f0u)

Comment: I had accidentally named two functions f3() causing it to not be run. Thanks!!